# Stripe payment intent with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, payment, checkout, applepay

I'm using stripe subscription payment in my rails application to charge my customers on my website. Does stripe subscription payment method uses the stripe paymentIntents or should I migrate to payment Intentets creations rather than payment subscriptions?

```
Stripe::Subscription.create(
  customer: user.stripe_id,
  items: [{ plan: plan.stripe_id }]
)
```

It already charges but I need to know should I migrate to payment intents or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd stick with the Subscriptions API. `Subscription` should create the necessary `Payment Intent` automatically.

If you've used Subscriptions in the past, it's worth reading up on how the flow has changed. Historically, your `Stripe::Subscription.create` call would either result in a charge and start the subscription, or it would fail and throw an exception.

That has [changed](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-03-14) with newer API versions. *Now a Subscription will be created regardless of whether the initial charge succeeds or fails*, but it can end up in an [incomplete](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#signup-4) state, and you will need to [take appropriate action](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#upgrading-integration) to [add a new payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#handling-failure) or have the user to [authenticate their card](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#handling-action-required).

Comment: As far i understand, I should make sure that update stripe to newer version and handle failed scenarios

Comment: Yes, that is right. In particular you'd want to upgrade your API Version  https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#how-can-i-upgrade-my-api

Comment: Okay, one last thing, what do you mean here by handling the **incomplete/unsuccessful payment** scenarios is that I should create no subscription till I get a successful payment.